# How to solve this problem with einstein summation index notation?

Tags: calculus

$$(a \cdot \nabla)a=(\nabla \times a) \times a   +  \nabla(\frac{1}{2}a^2)$$

I'm thinking to start with the second term on RHS but I have no clue what to do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually pretty straightforward once you get the hang of it:

$$\begin{align}[(\nabla \times a) \times a   +  \nabla(\frac{1}{2}a^2)]_p &= [(\nabla \times a) \times a]_p + [\nabla(\frac{1}{2}a^2)]_p \\ &= \epsilon_{pqr}(\nabla \times a)_qa_r + \frac 12\partial_p(a^2) \\ &= \epsilon_{pqr}\epsilon_{qst}(\partial_sa_t)a_r + \frac 12\partial_p(a_qa_q) \\ &= \epsilon_{qrp}\epsilon_{qst}(\partial_sa_t)a_r + \frac 12[(\partial_pa_q)a_q+a_q\partial_p a_q] \\ &= (\delta_{rs}\delta_{pt} - \delta_{rt}\delta_{ps})(\partial_sa_t)a_r+a_q\partial_p a_q \\ &= \delta_{rs}\delta_{pt}(\partial_sa_t)a_r - \delta_{rt}\delta_{ps}(\partial_sa_t)a_r+a_q\partial_p a_q \\ &= (\partial_ra_p)a_r - (\partial_pa_r)a_r+a_q\partial_p a_q \\ &= a_q\partial_qa_p - a_q\partial_pa_q+a_q\partial_pa_q \\ &= a_q\partial_qa_p \\ &= [(a\cdot \nabla)a]_p\ \ \ \ \square\end{align}$$

Let me know if you need me to explain a step.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm stuck on the fourth to last line; Did you sum over r to get the next line?

Comment: I just changed my dummy (summing) indices from $r$ to $q$.  It doesn't matter what you call your dummy indices as long as you change **both** of the indices in a given term at the same time.  Remember that $\sum_k v_k = \sum_r v_r$ -- the actual names of dummy indices don't matter.  So $$(\partial_ra_p)a_r = (\partial_qa_p)a_q = a_q\partial_qa_p$$

Comment: It was the dummy indices. Thanks